# how to define user roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need help with defining user roles. I have created my own authentication and am working on a custom authorization. However I need to define user roles. I have my roles created but I don't believe they have any true value with exactly what they should do.

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :password_confirmation, :about_me, :feet, :inches, :password, :birthday, :career, :children, :education, :email, :ethnicity, :gender, :height, :name, :password_digest, :politics, :religion, :sexuality, :user_drink, :user_smoke, :username, :zip_code
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }
  ROLES = %w[admin user guest banned]


  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can place a boolean field for each of your roles in your db so that you can directly call

if user.admin?
// your authorization logic goes here
end

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [`rolify`](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) and [`cancan`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

`rolify` allows you to easily define roles for your users:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.add_role :admin
```

Define roles on a specific class:

```
user.add_role :moderator, Forum
```

Define roles on specific instances:

```
user.add_role :moderator, Forum.first
```

`cancan` then allows you to define abilities, i.e. what a `user` can do. It works really well with `rolify`:

```
if user.has_role? :admin, User
  can :manage, :all
else
  can :manage, User, :id => user.id
end
```

The first ability definition defines that admins can manage (that is `read`, `create`, `update`, and `destroy`) everything.

The second ability definition says that non-admins can only manage themselves. i.e. I can only edit my own email address; I can't even view your user record!

The READMEs for both `gems` are excellent and link to further reading. I'm also going to be blogging about a fairly complete example that involves `rolify`, `cancan`, `aasm`, `omniauth` and Rails Observers in the next few days. The example will show how to create a state-machine (`aasm`) based email confirmation model, using `rolify` and `cancan` for permissions

Comment: Thanks but these are solutions for gems I am not using. I understand the recommendation of using them but for my first go at building an app I would like to do authorization from scratch. I did previously setup cancan and had it working, fairly easy to use. But I want to learn more of how authorization works.

Comment: Understood. `rolify` is probably a good place therefore to look at examples of what you might think about building for role support

Comment: Oh ok gotcha. Will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that on your controllers :

```
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_current_user_is_admin, :only => [:new,...]

  ...

  private

  def check_current_user_is_admin
    return if current_user.role == 'admin'
    redirect_to error_page
  end
end
```

It's an example, you can do what you want...

Comment: That seems to only verify if role is admin on page. I would like to define what each role can do, as I think that's the only missing part of my user roles.