# How do i make a user an admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a website in Ruby and I would like to have the option to sign up as an admin or a user. I have created the sign up system using devise and I would like to be able to give different permissions to different users, i.e Admins and Users. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

There's a comprehensive guide [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a post about using [Devise and CanCan](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/07/28/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-customizing-devise-controllers/) to accomplish what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can add boolean fields admin and users into your User model. So while creating you can assign admin or user role.

This question is answered here:
[how to define user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439182/how-to-define-user-roles/15445492#15445492)

Answer (score 0):

you can use devise + cancan and define roles like user and admin to separate common user and application admin.

```
class User < AB
  has_many :roles

  def is_admin?
    roles.include?(:admin)
  end
end

class Role < AB

end
```

and then check it in cancan's definition file like this

```
  can :update, Model do |model|
    user.admin?
  end
```

this video give you detail about it http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan